# Adding @angular/pwa not working on angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to run the command ng add @angular/pwa --*my project name* so that I can implement service workers in my angular project but the error that I'm returned is "The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found." If anyone can shed some light on what I can do to get past this error it would be much appreciated. I was upgrading from Angular CLI version 1.49. I have a feeling it has something to do with the angularcli.json file since the new version uses angular.json file.

This is also an exception when I try to use ng serve :
**Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used**

this is my version details:

```
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.0.1
Node: 10.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.1
@angular/cli                 7.0.1
@ngtools/webpack             1.10.2
@schematics/angular          7.0.1
@schematics/update           0.10.1
rxjs                         5.5.12
typescript                   3.1.1
webpack                      3.11.0
```

Comment: You have to add your project name after `--project`.

Comment: I have tried that, I am using my project name.

Comment: @angular/pwa was announced with the [release of Angular 6](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4). I suspect you'll have to update Angular to 6+ first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right regarding the new version using the updated `angular.json` file. See the following links on updating the cli, they should help: [Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b) and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215#issuecomment-433593036

In my case I did the following:

1. Uninstall the cli: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
2. Clear the npm cache: `npm cache verify`
3. Reinstall the angular cli: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

After installing the cli and generating your project, run the following inside the project directory where `name` is the name of the app as defined inside the angular.json file:

`ng add @angular/pwa --project name`

It is important to note that `name` is the name of the project as listed inside the `angular.json` file. Inside that file you should find a directive like this: `"defaultProject": "app",`. So in my case it will be:

`ng add @angular/pwa --project app`

Comment: `--project app`  made my day!

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't install the package when I ran the below command

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

When I was trying to fix this issue, The last version of @angular/pwa was v14.2.7  and my angular version was v11 so I installed a lower version of @angular/pwa and it worked for me. I ran this command

```
 ng add @angular/pwa@12.2.2
```

Answer (score 5):

I try updating the @angular-devkit/schematics-cli package to the latest version:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics-cli@latest
```

but that failed. In the end I this worked for me:

I updated the entire @angular/cli package to the latest version:

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

I did this on a new ng new project. It used the latest /pwa version
[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to update the CLI too in order to get the command to work

Answer (score 0):

For existing projects, ng generate won't be the best solution. Check the angular.json in your project folder.
"projects" key may have a project name. Underneath that you may find configurations for multiple commands.
Try with that project name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was changing the name only in the package.json file yet running ng add @angular/pwa --project name checks for the name in the angular.json file. So I had to update the name in the angular.json file as well and everything worked seemlessy then.

Answer (score 0):

Hamid answer worked for me. I am running Angular cli v8.2.2. For installing Angular 14 pwa did not work for me and kept on giving the error "this.tree.readText is not a function". Using the following command and installing pwa@12.2.2 worked for me:

ng add @angular/pwa@ --project projectNameInAngularJson

Comment: I think this answer is more a comment, may you have to less reputation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33371820)