# Angular CLI Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

When running the terminal commands `ng server` or `ng serve --live-reload=true`, I'm getting this issue:

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

Comment: Check if you have folder node_modules in the project folder, if not perform npm install

Comment: i already have node_modules folder.

Comment: I stumbled across this question when I had the same error message when trying to run "ng build". The answer for me was to run "npm run build"

Comment: I was in root directory, and getting this error :D. After `ng new project` I forgot to enter project directory.

Comment: I had the same problem as @DavutGürbüz , I was in the root directory and forgot to enter the project folder after creating angular project.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I was also getting this issue and solved by running below command.

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<WhateverVersionYouAreCurrentlyOn>
```

e.g.

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3
```

getting ref from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215#issuecomment-433593036)

Comment: It happens because new angular-cli depends uses angular.json  instead of .angular-cli.json as project file, and your answer takes care of this conversion

Comment: Note: The `--from=1.7.4` represents the version being migrated from, so the `1.7.4` should be changed to the angular version you were formerly using (eg: `5.2.10`, `6.0.0`, etc).

Comment: ng update @angular/cli << this worked for me with an existing project from angular 6 to 7

Comment: I was on 1.2.4 and got the following error: `The specified command update is invalid. For available options, see ``ng help``.` I solved it by updating angular-cli to 1.7.4 and then following this answer.

Comment: I have already updated version angular@cli (7.3.4) but still showing the same error. please help to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks. Working for me when i upgraded angular from 4.4.7 to 7

Comment: You don't even know how much your post helped me! I've spend a whole day strrugling with this migration, all in vain but after I found your post and ran this command everything started to work perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Was getting this error when scaffolding a new project with VS2017 and .Net Core. Couldn't fix it, with this or other answers. Wound up deleting the project solution, updating Angular and re-scaffolded, worked fine. Was mistakenly thinking VS would install the latest version, but seems that it simply runs the `ng new ClientApp` command in the solution dir and the version is dependent on what you have already installed via CLI =/

Comment: How do we know which version we are on

Comment: @VivekDev you can check the version by this command `ng version`. Go to your project directory and run this command

Comment: I successfully used this strategy to upgrade from Angular 5.2.5 to 10.0.1. All migration steps were carried out successfully.

Answer (score 140):

make sure that you are running the command in the application root folder..

Comment: to access your root folder use 
`pm> dir`
`pm> cd clientapp`
then if you have error message 
use the following 
`pm>ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false`

Comment: Simplest answer is often the right one, cheers buddy.

Answer (score 54):

if you have downloaded a project,do in the project

> npm install

Comment: my issue was private npm packages that was not installed

Comment: Same issue I had when trying the test projects for an angular tutorial

Answer (score 23):

Finally, the command below fixed the issue for me!

```
ng update --all --force
```

Comment: I tried `ng update @angular/cli` didn't work but `ng update --all --force` worked as expected what would be the difference ?

Comment: '--all' functionality has been removed as updating multiple packages at once is not recommended. To update packages which don’t provide 'ng update' capabilities in your workspace 'package.json' use 'npm update' instead.

Answer (score 18):

> Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found
>
> Problem was missing angular.json files.

```
    ng update --all --force
```

Tested in Angular 7+

Answer (score 10):

It was silly me but need to leave comment maybe I save someone else some hassle. **Same message happens if you** multitask and have multiple projects so some of project is nested inside project folder like `projectFolder/subProject/projectOne` so I was in `projectFolder/subProject` trying to run command `ng serve`.

**Make sure you are in correct folder** because same error will occur if you are in wrong folder and conf and build is missing!

Answer (score 6):

It was happening in my existing project as I tried to update to latest `node` and `npm` packages:

1. Uninstall global: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
2. Reset Cache: `npm cache clean` or `npm cache verify` (for `npm version` > 5)
3. Install latest: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: The only issue with uninstalling and installing npm is that it may break 3rd party libraries that are installed. Another work around would be to just copy paste package.json and package-lock.json from repo and then do npm-update.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have set the new angular version configuration in your project. The new angular cli uses angular.json and not .angular-cli.json for its configuration.

Follow [migration guide](https://update.angular.io/).

Answer (score 3):

In your Package Manager Console run the command

```
PM> cd NameofApp
```

then you can try to run the command there.For instance

```
PM > ng generate component Home
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you try to run the Angular command "ng s" or "ng serve" on the other folder instead of the root folder of the Angular application.

Also upgrade the Angular using the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

This will sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

This error may be occur when we are in wrong directory.so use cd command to change your directory.
It's not very evident from the above comment that which specific command is giving 
this error so this answer is based on assumption that you are running ng serve 
outside the root folder/actual project folder. That's why it's giving error because 
cli commands require conf & build files to run the cli build.

```
These should be the steps:
npm install -g @angular/cli  //corrected from 'angular-cli'
ng new projectname
cd projectname
ng serve
open http://localhost:4200
```

Answer (score 3):

to reinstall back freshly the application is way better rather than update or editing some config that is not recognize by npm due to missing config or we are not really sure what is wrong.

I choose @Tinu solution is work

Step 1) npm install -g @angular/cli

Step 2) ng new my-angular-project

Step 3) cd my-angular-project

Step 4) ng serve --open

just made backup for our current source code and put it back to new angular project that be created.

Answer (score 3):

Change to your app folder, and run generate command again:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This error usually can be traced back to an update to our global or local CLI runtime.  To check if this is the problem, we need to review the `package.json` file. There, we should look for the *@angular/cli* dependency. This should indicate the CLI version that was used to create our project. Lets make a note of this value, as we need to use it to migrate our project later on.

We should now compare to the current CLI runtime by entering the following command on the terminal window.

```sh
ng v
```

[image: output of ng v]

> If you get error `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, scandir '~/your-app/node_modules'`, then you forgot
>   to run `npm install`

The console should display the current CLI version. If the **versions are different**, we need to migrate the project to the new CLI version by running the command below.  Note that the *from* version parameter should set to the value found for the *@angular/cli* setting.

```sh
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.6.7
```

We should now take a look at our project and should notice changes to the CLI dependency version in the `package.json` file. Also depending on your CLI version, the `.angular-cli.json` file is deleted, and a new `angular.json` file is created. This is the project file that the new CLI is looking for and thus the source of the error of no project found. By adding this file, we should be able to be back on track on run our project again.

We should be able to enter the following command and the project should be loading fine.

```sh
ng server
```

Thanks to [ozkary](https://www.ozkary.com/2019/01/angular-serve-command-requires-angular-project.html)

Comment: very well explained

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Angular7 because we need to go the root folder before run your application. Go to the root folder of your app and run the command. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I came across, but I solved by following these steps of code.

```
Step 1) npm install -g @angular/cli
Step 2) ng new my-angular-project
Step 3) cd my-angular-project
Step 4) ng serve --open
```

Comment: Why we have to create a new project? I want this to be done for existing one

Comment: why create a new project ? If a anyone is having the problem in existing project

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the project you are running is not an angular project.
Though you have downloaded an angular project but have not installed all the dependencies thats why the ng serve command is not available to you.

Just navigate to the path where the project is stored and use the command

```
npm install
```

(Note - Node.js should be installed in your system and if you are using Angular 2 or above angular cli should also be installed in your system before you run this command.
To check if the node.js is installed n your system
1) Open cmd (any path- as node should be globally installed in your system)
2) use command

```
node -v
npm -v
```

to get node and npm version)

One more important thing:
The angular cli version won't make a difference if the version installed in your system is higher than the version required by the project.
It will give a warning but you can ignore the warning.

Comment: haha my case is exactly like that, npm install worked for me, it was the dependencies that made noise

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the above But for me it was solved by

`npm start`

Comment: this should be in the comment section

Comment: @Pardeep I have tried all the above answer but npm start worked me. so it will helpful for the other developer. if it is made as eye catching answer rather than keeping in the comments

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have created angular App using below command, then running ng serve in created Project folder.

```
ng new Project_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

This project doesn't use the angular cli, it uses webpack directly. To start run the command

> npm start

Comment: this command only helped me

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error. The reason is that new angular cli update makes angular-cli.json redundant, and it is replaced with angular.json instead. My previous Angular Cli version is 1.7.4, so to make the change, I ran the following command, it will make the conversion for you:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Comment: Unknown option: '--target' npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when,

I had created new angular project using old angular-cli version (1.4.7)
I then updated angular-cli using below commands (**DO NOT DO THE BELOW TO UPDATE CLI**)

- `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install -g  @angular/cli@latest`

Now when I tried `ng serve`, i was getting same error like you

```
Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found
```

**DO BELOW TO UPDATE CLI**

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to change my directory, so just after running the command :

> ng new AngularProject

execute another command :

> cd AngularProject

and `ng serve` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As Usman said, i had a lot of trouble first time, I was following a tutorial. I had not set my directory to the project directory hence got this error.

I solved the issue by

1. Setting the correct root directory to where my project was `cd myproject`
2. Compile the app - `ng serve`

That was it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because we are hitting ng serve command in some other path.This can be solved by hitting ng serve or npm start command on the path where exactly the our project resides(take path until the folder which contains src,node_modules,etc.)

F:\project\AngularDemo\AngularDemoapp> ng serve

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to confirm if you are in the directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ionciv1, in the file `ionic.config.json` delete the angular type key and it worked correctly

example:

```
  {
  "name": "nombre",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular", // delete
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "sass",
    "templatecache",
    "ng_annotate",
    "useref",
    "watch"
  ],
  "watchPatterns": [
    "www/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*"
  ],
  "browsers": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "browser": "crosswalk",
      "version": "12.41.296.5"
    }
  ],
  "id": "0.1"
}
```

solved

```
     {
      "name": "nombre",
      "integrations": {
        "cordova": {}
      },
      "gulpStartupTasks": [
        "sass",
        "templatecache",
        "ng_annotate",
        "useref",
        "watch"
      ],
      "watchPatterns": [
        "www/**/*",
        "!www/lib/**/*"
      ],
      "browsers": [
        {
          "platform": "android",
          "browser": "crosswalk",
          "version": "12.41.296.5"
        }
      ],
      "id": "0.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that I was trying to execute the *ng serve* command in a project created with Ruby on Rails. In other words, I had to run the *rails -s* command for Ruby on Rails.
I got confused because Angular was built into Ruby on Rails so I had to run the  *rails -s* command to start my project's local server and it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same error. So, i first went to root folder(folder containing angular.json file) and then

```
run "npm install" command(creating node modules),
then run "npm audit fix --force"
and then run "ng build",(building project)
and "ng serve"  (runnning project)
```

Answer (score 1):

this 3 commands helped me
npm install --force
npm audit fix --force
npm start

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure if you are running ng serve that you stop it first...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was getting same issue on *ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS*. No above options worked as I was using *NVM (Node Version manager.)* Solution is
*before creating project*,use command
**nvm use 10**
(my node version was 10.15.0, so I used "nvm use 10")
It will show you output-
**Now using node v10.15.0 (npm v6.4.1)**
Versions will vary as per individual systems.
then create new project.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the angular with command 'ng update --all'. It will take time but make sure your all components are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are inside your project folder or not and try the command `ng serve` again

I got the same error since I tried `ng serve` command outside of my project

Example :: 
let's say you have a project with name "Ecommerce" traverse into the folder and try the command  `ng serve`
open terminal 
cd Ecommerce 
ng serve

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:

```
ng generate component nameComponent --module app.module
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when didn't install angular core:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.0
Node: 11.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: undefined
...
```

So I run

```
npm i @angular/core
```

which gave me ng -v

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.0
Node: 11.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.13
... core
```

Then I run

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=8.2.13
```

removed node_modules

```
npm install
cd <project name>
ng serve
```

And it worked!

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ** ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled
>   successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with VS Code, turns out that enabling detection of Angular Icons fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Even `ng update --all --force` doesn't work?

It might be simply when you're performing `Angular` upgrade from version when `.angular-cli.json` (for example `Angular 4`) has been used to one of the newer versions having `angular.json`. In that case you might need to delete the `.angular-cli.json` and replace with equivalent metadata `angular.json`. After that, you'll be able to perform update from one command or step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Any issue in your angular.jason file can cause this error. So if the file is missing in your directory or it has an error that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try --> npx ng serve

I've got this same error running ng serve and I've fixed it running npx ng serve

Answer (score 0):

I had started off with a theme sample project base. It's angular.json

```
 "projects": {
    "<project name>": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
    ...
```

It also has

```
 "defaultProject": "<project name>",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
```

Matching the project name with this solved my problem on Angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake of running ng server in the parent directory of the Angular application, OP got the answer but if anyone is searching the answer might want to cd into the application directory too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31356476)

Answer (score 0):

Just go on to your project name in vs code and right click on that project name there you'll find "Open in integrated terminal" there you type --ng serve-- that how it helps me and fixed my problem as well. Which happened because of incorrect path!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your base or folder paths
Open your command prompt or terminal and run ng new command to create the new Angular application.

D:\Angular Applications>ng new test-app
It will create a new folder called test-app and that folder contains our Angular source code.

Now D:\Angular Applications\test-app is our Angular project root directory.

You have to navigate to project root directory and then you have to run ng serve.

D:\Angular Applications> cd test-app

D:\Angular Applications\test-app>ng serve

Its should works

Answer (score -1):

it kept giving me the same errors. i tried all the commands on this page with no avail. i turned the computer off and on. it worked for me.

Comment: `i tried all the commands on this page` and then you rebooted. Which means at least one of these solutions worked, but now you don't know which one. The reboot itself isn't likely to be the sole solution.