# What is a project definition in Angular?

Tags: angular, travis-ci

When I test my Angular project on Travis-CI, two exceptions emerged:

```
$ ng test
The test command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
The command "ng test" exited with 1.

$ ng e2e
The e2e command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
The command "ng e2e" exited with 1.
```

---

The error message is pretty confusing.
I googled about "*Angular project definition*",
but nothing relevant is found.

I checked out [Angular CLI wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki),
but there is no useful information about `ng test` and `ng e2e`,
not to mention the definition of "*project definition*".

---

My Github project:

https://github.com/donizyo/ng-dementor

My development environment:

```
$ ng version
Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 11.1.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.3
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.3
@angular/cli                 7.0.3
@schematics/angular          7.0.3
@schematics/update           0.10.3
rxjs                         5.5.12
typescript                   2.5.3
```

Raw log of Travis-CI can be found [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/450107369/log.txt).

---

**UPDATE 1**

I just installed the lastest Angular CLI (v7.0.4) on my PC,

```
$ ng version
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: <error>
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          7.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.10.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.3.3 (cli-only)
typescript                   3.1.3 (cli-only)
```

and generated a new project `testprj` with it.

When I execute `ng test` in directory `My Projects/testprj/`,
everything goes fine.
Karma v3.0.0 server was started, Chrome browser was launched.

However when I execute `ng test` in directory `My Projects/ng-dementor/`,
Angular CLI gives me nothing but "*The test command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.*"

---

**UPDATE 2**

I updated my Angular CLI
according to [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/).
Now my develop environment is:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.4
@angular/cli                      7.0.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.4
@schematics/angular               7.0.4
@schematics/update                0.10.4
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.5.3
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Comment: You need to check the doc here: https://angular.io/cli/test

Comment: @wannadream I just tried `ng test src` and `ng e2e src`, still failing. :0

Comment: no, shouldn't it be 'ng test ng-dementor'? project parameter needs the name, not the folder.

Comment: can't i just leave <project> blank?

Comment: i just noticed that when i execute `ng test` (without <project> argument) in a project generated with angular/cli@7.0.4, karma runs normally.

Comment: what are your project definitions in angular.json? when you create a new project with ng new projectname there will be 2 projects defined in angular.json - compare your angular.json with that of a new project and make sure your project definitions therein are correct

Comment: @danday74 It's called "ng-dementor" in file ".angular-cli.json"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer covers Angular 6, but it looks like you are using an older Angular version so this might not work exactly as is. You could upgrade to 6 as detailed here:

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

So anyway in Angular 6 you will find these entries in `angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MYPROJECT": {
      // more stuff
    }
  },
  // more stuff
  "defaultProject": "MYPROJECT"
}
```

To test this project you can run:

```
ng test
```

OR

```
ng test MYPROJECT
```

If you run this:

```
ng test --help
```

It will provide some feedback on how to use the command for your specific version of Angular.

Also see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test) but this is Angular 6 specific.

See also [Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

Also, are your global installs on travis the same as on your local machine?

If you need some packages installed globally, add this to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
- npm install -g your-package-name
```

Comment: Sir, your link to _blog.angular.io_ yields 504 error. I don't know what's the content of that page. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: try now, it didn't seem to like the # in the URL which was an anchor link, I've removed the anchor link, the section you want is titled ng update, scroll down a little

Comment: After I followed [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) step by step, `ng test` runs correctly now, thx.