# Angular 2 project not running

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I have downloaded a MEAN stack project saved on bitbucket and trying to run front end part (Angular 2) locally by navigating to the angular folder and doing ng serve but it is giving following error

> "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found."

I have installed latest version(7.0.4) of angular cli on my local machine.

Please help with this problem.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: is there any package.json file? did you do ```npm i``` ?

Comment: Yes I did npm install and all node modules are installed properly with package.json file.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to latest version of angular cli.This can be achieved using :

**`ng update @angular/cli`**

Comment: What if I don't want update the project from angular 2 to latest version ?

Comment: After running above command I am getting "Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping."

Comment: Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:
    
      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/core                      2.4.10 -> 7.0.2          ng update @angular/core
      rxjs                               5.5.12 -> 6.3.3          ng update rxjs
    
    
    There might be additional packages that are outdated.
    Run "ng update --all" to try to update all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that new angular cli update makes `angular-cli.json` redundant, and it is replaced with `angular.json` instead.

Try

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

OR

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from={previous angular version}
```