# The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: node.js, angular

I developed an application ( angular2 nodejs), but now when I open it, I get the following error:

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I do not find the problem knowing that I made an update to the cli

```
*Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 10.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 2.4.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    <error>
@angular-devkit/core         <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics   <error>
@angular/router              3.4.10
@angular/tsc-wrapped         0.5.2
@ngtools/json-schema         1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack             1.10.2
@schematics/angular          <error>
@schematics/update           <error>
rxjs                         5.5.11
typescript                   2.0.10
webpack                      2.2.0*
```

**this is my .json package**

```
{
  "name": "angular-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.8",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your package.json file

Comment: i update my code and i add my package.json @sur

Comment: I advice you upgrade your client side. refer this link https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-7-beta-within-10-minutes-c14fc380edd

Comment: @Suryan I UPDATE MY CODE

Comment: I can not find a solution

Comment: Your error message is self explanatory that you are serving or `ng serve` in the wrong folder which isn't angular or in other words unable to find the `package.json` file of the client

Comment: I'm sure I'm in the right path @Suryan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, delete or rename 'angular.json' then create a new one.

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

You may also need up update typescript if you get error.

Also follow the step here: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips that might be useful for this case:

1. Be sure you are in the root folder when you run `ng serve`
2. Use `npm install`
3. use `npm start`