# How can I create an Angular brand new component into this folder? Why am I obtaining this error message using Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components, javascript-framework

I am an absolute beginner in Angular and I am finding some problem creating a component using the Angular CLI into an Angular project on which I am working on.

I manually created a subfolder (into my Angular project) in which I want create my new component, something like:

```
C:\Users\myusre\Source\Workspaces\MySolution\MyProject\WebProject\app\maildetail\maildetail-sidebar
```

I access to this folder into my shell and I execute this statment:

```
ng generate component main-detail-protocollo-sidebar
```

so I expect to obtain a new directory (into the previous directory) for my new component.

But I am obtaining this error message:

```
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I create a brand new component directly into the previous folder?

Comment: I believe is a bug not totally solved: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12198 and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215 -- Have you tried `ng g c testComponent`? I know is the same thing, but just for curiosity

Comment: @JacopoSciampi mmm same problem

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be inside your project folder either `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` and try to run the generate command

`ng generate component folder/main-detail-protocollo-sidebar --flat`

Usually `cli` will generate a folder when you run the `generate` command to avoid that you can use `--flat`

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be into the folder containing your angular.json

From there you can specify subpath in the component name, something likje this:

```
ng generate component subfolder/main-detail-protocollo-sidebar
```

Comment: WOW this project doesn't contain the angular.json file. It is a .NET project that encapsulate Angular in some way :-/