# getting error after updating angular core & angular cli from v5.1 to v7.2

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular-cli-v7

ive updated the angular core form 5.1 to 7.2 also angular-cli

after when i try to serve my application it gives me error 
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

thanks

[Angular Cli Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

already tried this solution but it didn't work

here is my version description

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.2
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.2
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.2
@angular/cli                 7.2.2
@schematics/angular          7.2.2
@schematics/update           0.12.2
rxjs                         5.5.12
typescript                   2.5.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried killing your serve command first and then starting it? basically, you need to restart it. Also, make sure you are running it in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for replying i tried to find port "netstat -ano | findstr :4200" but there is no running process, and im executing serve command in project root folder so that wont be an issue