# ng serve not startable anymore after upgrade

Tags: angular

I have update my angular and I get the following error:

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

I have done already following:

```
D:\IntelliJProjects\springboottests\src\main\frontend2>ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only
    Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping.
    We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!

D:\IntelliJProjects\springboottests\src\main\frontend2>ng serve
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

D:\IntelliJProjects\springboottests\src\main\frontend2>
```

I am in the folder with package.json and angular-cli.json.

I have tried already suggestions from stackoverflow, but nothing helped.

My version:

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.2 (cli-only)
@angular/tsc-wrapped         0.5.2
@ngtools/json-schema         1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack             1.10.2
@schematics/angular          7.2.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.12.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.4
webpack                      2.2.0
```

any help ?

Comment: Did you change Node.js version on your system ?

Comment: Not sure but I guess. I have updated with : ng update --all

Comment: are you able to create new project using cli command ?

Comment: `The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.` it is literally telling you what the problem is. This is not an Angular project.

Comment: I can read that too :-) But I have my angular project running before the upgrade. I can see the .json files in the folder. So there must something chagend.

Comment: I have added a empty angular.json and I get another error that it is empty. It seems they changed the projectfile name. How can I migrate that file ? just move it ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the `ng serve` command from the angular application root folder.
If it is already the case then may be try this:

- Get your angular cli current version with `ng -v`
- ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=[angular cli version]

from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

Comment: I am in the folder of package.json. I did the same you suggested, but it just says. "We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!" . Then ng server -> "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

Comment: In the snippet from your question, you didn't specify any version: `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only`

Comment: I have done with "ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=7.2.2", but still the same problem.

Comment: I have added a empty angular.json and I get another error that it is empty. It seems they changed the projectfile name. How can I migrate that file ? just move it ?

Comment: My guess is that the first time you updated the angular cli you didn't specify the version for `--from` option, and your new angular cli version use `angular.json` instead of `angular-cli.json`, do you remember your angular cli version before first update ?

Comment: I guess you are right. That was my fault. So I have to setup from scratch and copy my code into the new project, right ?

Comment: I would certainly try.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of angular.json file
just run  ng update @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

for me

> `npm i --force`

worked you can try this too