# Re-Install Angular Correctly

Tags: angular

I had problems with my dependencies in Angular so i reinstalled it in my project.
So, what I did was this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

However now, when trying to use npm start or ng serve, this happens

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular@0.0.0 start script.
```

additional to that, when trying the npm install command I get strange warnings:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 7337 packages in 4.116s
found 20 vulnerabilities (3 low, 14 moderate, 3 high)
```

It worked before uninstalling (except for the dependencies) so i'm getting really frustrated.

First thing I found googling this problem of course was

[Angular CLI Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

but after doing this, the problem still consisted.

How can I reinstall Angular correctly?

Comment: are you running npm install in correct folder? Kinda sounds like you dont.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

Comment: @AJT82 It's definitely in the right folder

Comment: Yeah, that error is often present when you run the final `npm install` and  `ng serve` **outside the project folder**, like  error kind of suggests, but if you are indeed in the app folder, it's something else :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
    npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache clean
    npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then when it gets done successfully you may try:

ng --version

Comment: I tried this and still got the same error. When running ng --version i get this 'Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 12.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.11'

Comment: try this command, npm install --no-optional --no-shrinkwrap --no-package-lock

Comment: Okay with this, the error changed to Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Component'.

Comment: which was solved by rm -rf node_modules/
npm install, your answer is the correct one.

Comment: After all this I'm still getting: This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0, but Angular version 16.2.1 was found instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there has been an update to checking the version.

OLD:  ng --version

NOW:  ng version

As of 2-AUG-2022