# Ng serve does nothing

Tags: angular-cli

I have a problem to run and even build my project. Every ng command that I try to be executed does nothing and even displays nothing. Only one exception is for **ng version** command, that shows versions of various packages. It worked well before I made update of cli from 13 to 14 version, also I made some other updates for angular core and material, but updating cli was the main trigger. I tried to reboot laptop or change some properties in tsconfig.json, but nothing helped

Comment: try doing a [clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080345/9890873)

Comment: I made so, and tried to execute **ng --version**, but it wrote `Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.` but **ng version** command executes well

Comment: The correct usage is `ng version` and not `ng --version`. You can get help for your command using `ng version --help`

Comment: Yes I know about **ng version**, but **ng serve** and **ng build** makes nothing and I can't start localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using angular 15? If you answer yes only

> `ng version`

it's ok for you, otherwise ng --help and will list the command for you

Comment: I already solved a problem for my pet project by myself, but as it was long ago I don't remember clearly how I did it. Maybe problem was with appropriate nodejs version