# Unable to execute the angular app with ng

Tags: angular

I'm newbie for working on angular.
when I;m trying to execute the application from the terminal with the commmand "ng serve --open" I'm getting an error stating as like below :

**"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."**

I had taken a search in google I found that my ng versions and node versions should be same. I had cheked the versions with "ng v" command the versions are as like below :

angular cli : 8.3.22
node : 12.14.1

I'm unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: you need to make sure you are in the project root (cd into it))

Comment: Also there's no relation between angular-cli and nodejs version.

Comment: point your command prompt to project folder and run **ng serve**

Comment: @AndrewAllen Its working with change of root directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line make sure you are in the folder of your angular application and after tap

> ng serve --open

Answer (score 0):

Navigate into the project by issuing the command cd

Answer (score 0):

"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."  -- this says you are running ng command outside of your project

Answer (score 0):

run this command

ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3

you can refer this post also [Angular CLI Error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)