# Migration failed: Could not find configuration file

Tags: angular

I have downloaded the angular project and executed `npm install` and `ng serve`

when I hit `ng serve` it it giving me error.

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

Hence I have followed [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096996/angular-cli-error-the-serve-command-requires-to-be-run-in-an-angular-project-b)

when I try to execute `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3` I am getting the following error.

```
** Executing migrations of package '@angular/cli' **

> Update an Angular CLI project to version 6.
× Migration failed: Could not find configuration file
  See "C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Jg9VXW\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you are running ```ng serve``` in the exact folder of your angular application..

Comment: yeah, I am executing `ng serve` in the parent folder of the project

Comment: your parent folder, does it have node_modules folder in it?

Comment: it is having `node_modules` folder